# Fazer loop percorrer de 20 em 20 linhas

Tags: javascript, for

Gostaria que, a cada clique no botão contasse, e o mesmo invocaria a `variavel` para alterar a **inicialização** e a **condição** do *laço* `for`, para um valor númerico de **20 em 20**.

Seria tipo percorrer do **0** à **20** e esperar outro clique. Logo noutro clique continuasse do **20** à **40** e aguardar novamente o próximo clique, que agora irá parti do **40** à **60** e parar novamente, e etc...

Isto é, o *Laço* `for` só é alterado na **inicialização** e a sua **condição**

for (***inicialização; condição;*** incremento) {
...
}

**Demonstração:**

No *primeiro clique*

for (i = **20**; i < **40**; incremento) {
...
}

No *segundo clique*

for (i = **40**; i < **60**; incremento) {
...
}

No *terceiro clique*

for (i = **60**; i < **80**; incremento) {
...
}

e assim por diante, a cada clique.

> **Explicando** - Aonde é **0** passa a ser **20** após o *primeiro clique*, logo onde era **20** torna-se **40** após o *segundo clique*, e assim se vai a cada clique no botão, sucessivamente, um após outro clique no botão será alterado seus valores.
>
> Acho que ficou claro. Mudança dinâmica na sintaxe do loop a cada clique.

Comment: for (var i = 10; i < x; i += 10)

Comment: Explique melhor o último parágrafo, ele está confuso. Quer incrementar a inicialização? Tente certeza disto? Pra que? Quer incrementar a condição? Como?

Comment: O `i` terá o valor incremental de 1 mesmo? Tipo, será de 20 à 30, mas ele irá percorrer 21,22,23,24... E assim até chegar 30?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se eu entendi a sua pergunta, basta criar uma variável com um scopo maior para ser o seu "contador" de click's, aplicando a regra no lool a cada clique. Veja um exemplo simples:

```html
<p id="resultado">

</p>

<script> 
  var contador = 0;
  var test =  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML;
  
  function calcular(){
   console.log(contador);
    var i = 10 + contador;
    var c = 20 + contador;

     for ( i; i < c; i++) {
     console.log(i)
        test += ' - ' + i;
    }
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = test;
    contador += 10;
  }
</script>

<button onclick="calcular()">
Calcular
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

o fromInclusive (inicialização) e o toExclusive (condição) devem vir de algum lugar. por exemplo, duas caixas de texto.:

```js
var fromInclusive = document.getElementById("fromInclusive");
var toExclusive = document.getElementById("toExclusive");
var executar = document.getElementById("executar");
var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");


executar.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  var from = parseInt(fromInclusive.value);
  var to = parseInt(toExclusive.value);
  var result = 0;
  
  for (var indice = from; indice < to; indice++) {
    result += indice;
  }
  
  resultado.textContent = result;
  
  var diff = to - from;
  fromInclusive.value = from + diff;
  toExclusive.value = to + diff;
});
```

```html
<div>
  <label>
    fromInclusive:
    <input id="fromInclusive" type="text" value="0" />
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    toExclusive:
    <input id="toExclusive" type="text" value="10" />
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <input id="executar" type="button" value="Somar Valores" />
  <span id="resultado"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simples assim:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i+=10) 
{
    // ...
}
```

O incrementador `++` pode ser parametrizado.

- `++` incremento de **1**;
- `+=n` incremento de **n**, onde **n** deve >= 1;

Ele também pode ser um decrementador:

- `--` decremento de **1**;
- `-=n` decremento de **n**, onde **n** >= 1;

Answer (score 2):

Depois de algumas tentativas baseado nas repostas aqui dos colegas, tive uma visão clara, basta definir duas variável com um [scopo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escopo_%28computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29) maior para ser **inicialização** e outra para **condição**, já o *"contador de cliques"* fica a parte. Vejamos o resultado disso, logo abaixo:

```js
var n = 0; // Variável de Inicialização do laço  
        var i = 0; // Variável de Condição do laço  
        var j = 0; // Esta é variável que tão somente conta os cliques no botão

        function mais() {

            // Logo no primeiro clique inicia-se o Salto de 20 em 20 na declaração 2 - condição 
            i += 20;

            // Exibi o(s) número(s) de clique(s) dado(s)
            document.getElementById('view').textContent = i;
            // Nesta linha iremos quebrar/dividir o(s) dado(s) de cada string
            barra = dados.split("|");

            for (x = n; x < i; x++) {
                if (barra[x]) {

                    // Logo abaixo exibimos a informação na página de cada string

                    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML += "<br>" + barra[x] + "<br>";
                }
            }
            // No segundo clique inicia-se o Salto de 20 em 20 na declaração 1 - inicialização 
            // Isto se faz necessário para que não repita as primeiras linhas exibidas 
            // mas que de continuidade nas seguintes após as primeiras e assim por diante ...
            if (j) {
                n += 20
            }
        }
        dados = //Isto é a nosso banco de dados para o nosso exemplo

            // O 1º clique - Mostra a listagem 1 do A - E 
            "|A|Tam.: G|Cod.: 01|" +
            "|B|Tam.: M|Cod.: 02|" +
            "|C|Tam.: P|Cod.: 03|" +
            "|D|Tam.: P|Cod.: 04|" +
            "|E|Tam.: G|Cod.: 05|" +
            // O 2º clique - Mostra a listagem 2 do F - J 
            "|F|Tam.: P|Cod.: 06|" +
            "|G|Tam.: M|Cod.: 07|" +
            "|H|Tam.: P|Cod.: 08|" +
            "|I|Tam.: P|Cod.: 09|" +
            "|J|Tam.: G|Cod.: 10|" +
            // O 3º clique - Mostra a listagem 3 do K - O 
            "|K|Tam.: G|Cod.: 11|" +
            "|L|Tam.: M|Cod.: 12|" +
            "|M|Tam.: P|Cod.: 13|" +
            "|N|Tam.: P|Cod.: 14|" +
            "|O|Tam.: G|Cod.: 15|" +
            // O 4º clique - Mostra a listagem 4 do P - T 
            "|P|Tam.: G|Cod.: 16|" +
            "|Q|Tam.: M|Cod.: 17|" +
            "|R|Tam.: P|Cod.: 18|" +
            "|S|Tam.: P|Cod.: 19|" +
            "|T|Tam.: G|Cod.: 20|" +
            // O 5º clique - Mostra a listagem 5 do U - Y
            "|U|Tam.: G|Cod.: 21|" +
            "|V|Tam.: M|Cod.: 22|" +
            "|W|Tam.: P|Cod.: 23|" +
            "|X|Tam.: P|Cod.: 24|" +
            "|Y|Tam.: G|Cod.: 25|";
```

```html
    <center>

        <input type="button" onclick="mais(j++)" value="Conta">

        <div id="view"></div>

        <hr>

        <div id="list"></div>

    </center>
```

---

Mas porque teria que somar/percorrer de 20 em 20?

Digo! - Para o meu propósito como podem analisar estou buscando os dados de dentro de um *método* `new String()`.

No entanto, queria somente exibir ***5 strings*** por clique.

A cada dados entre as aspas duplas, temos as barras "**|**", que por sua vez faz a divisão dos dados, à saber são: ***4 barras*** por [string](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadeia_de_caracteres).

Sabendo disso, multiplica-se `4 barras` por `5 strings` = `20 linhas`

Sendo assim, cria-se as `var n=0`, `n += 20` e a `var i=0`, `i += 20` para alterar a *declaração 1* e *declaração 2* do laço `for`

Então temos o salto de ***20 em 20 linhas***

> **NOTA** - o que tinha em mente quando fiz esta pergunta era criar um efeito **sroll infinito** em Javascript Puro. Percebi que poderia fazê-lo com um `loop` jutamente com o *método* `scrollTop()`. Foi nessa intenção que cheguei a conclusão que, não só daria para criar o efeito **scroll infinito** com essa lógica, mas também, fazer paginação estática e randomizar a informações na página.
>
> Pois não poderia utilizar a *sintaxe* do `for` como ela é em si, não teria como percorrer em sequência(números ordinais), naturalmente é assim que um laço faz.  Se eu o fizesse assim, a cada clique no botão ele me retornaria só a vigesima(última) linha de cada `string`.